# how do I see the classpath from ant?

Tags: java, netbeans, ant, build, classpath

From Ant, how do I enumerate the JAR's being used to build this project?

Looking at the `projecthelp` for this project:

```
thufir@doge:~/NetBeansProjects/PointToPointSender$ 
thufir@doge:~/NetBeansProjects/PointToPointSender$ ant -p build.xml -verbose | grep copylibs
 -do-jar-copylibs
 -init-macrodef-copylibs
thufir@doge:~/NetBeansProjects/PointToPointSender$
```

In the `build-impl.xml` I see:

```
<property name="copylibs.rebase" value="true"/>
<available file="${meta.inf.dir}/persistence.xml" property="has.persistence.xml"/>
<condition property="junit.available">
    <or>
        <available classname="org.junit.Test" classpath="${run.test.classpath}"/>
        <available classname="junit.framework.Test" classpath="${run.test.classpath}"/>
    </or>
</condition>
```

as well as, in `project.properties` the `excludes` and `classpath properties`:

```
excludes=
file.reference.activemq.jar=/home/thufir/jars/apache-activemq-5.11.1/bin/activemq.jar
file.reference.wrapper.jar=/home/thufir/jars/apache-activemq-5.11.1/bin/wrapper.jar
includes=**
jar.compress=false
javac.classpath=\
    ${libs.javaee-api-7.0.classpath}:\
    ${file.reference.activemq.jar}:\
    ${file.reference.wrapper.jar}
```

From the CLI, will Ant enumerate the JAR's on the classpath?

The ideal command would be:  `ant -p -show-classpath` although I suppose it depends on how Netbeans defines the classpath.

Comment: There is no automatic classpath management in ANT. You create ANT "path" declarations and associate these with "javac" or "java" task declarations using classpath references. Basically ANT gives gives you great control, but you'll need to read the build file. For something to automatically take care of these details for you I would recommend using Maven instead. Completely different and more opinionated build tool but useful when you don't want to dig too much into how your build works. Hope this helps.

Comment: it helps enough to make me look at gradle :)   I remember playing with rake and ant, and just being amazed at rake over ant.  I don't think rake is quite as mainstream as gradle (?), so I think it's time to do some learnin' and dig into this build process a bit.  The IDE is nice when the magic works, but when it doesn't...very frustrating.

Comment: You can run ant with the `-d` option (debug) and the output will list out the classpath being used when the Java compiler is invoked.  I recommend saving the log output to a file since debug mode can generate a lot of output.